# Change SCSS variables from other files

Tags: css, sass

My ultimate goal is to make one template file which i can modify for different pages.
My approach was to create a `template.scss` and a `modifier.scss`

in `template.scss` I set

```
$background: green; 
background: $background
```

in `modifier.scss` I set

```
@import 'template';
$background: red;
```

and expect the background to change, however nothing happens.
obviously this is the wrong approach, how should i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that this approach won't work. Think about how those files would be interpreted.

**Example**

*template.scss*

```
$background:   green; 
background: $background
```

*modifier.scss*

```
@import 'template';
$background: red;
```

In this case you're essentially doing:

```
$background: green; 
background: $background
$background: red;
```

The end effect is `background` is set to `green`, and the `$background` variable is redefined to `red` in the end.

You would need to define `background: $background` again within `modifier.scss` in order for you current setup to work.

**A Different Approach**

One approach is to define your base styles within one file, modifier styles within another, and then set your CSS properties within a final file. Like this:

*template.scss*

```
$background: green;
```

*modifier.scss*

```
$background: red;
```

*styles.scss*

```
background: $background;
```

Comment: okay, makes sense. the problem is though, that i don't want to assign different scss files to different pages, but that they are compiled to one. i therefore want to set a general `class { background: $background}` in _template.scss_ and a more specific `class.extra {background: $background}` in _modifier.scss_ without having to write the whole file twice

Comment: that's possible, but you'd need to redefine `class.extra {background: $background;}` in `modifier.scss`. And would use `class` on one page, and `class.extra` on the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can make that variable a **`!default`** in your `template.scss` and import latter file in a different order in `modifier.scss`.

**[Variable Defaults: !default](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_)** (Sass reference)

In `template.scss`

```
$background: green !default; 
background: $background;
```

and then in `modifier.scss`

```
$background: red;
@import 'template';
```

green shouldn't be assigned to the variable if it was already set to red, which is the case in `modifier.scss` (edit: s/won't/shouldn't I didn't test it yet with partials)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, so much easier, have my upvote! I can't believe I didn't know that for several years... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Using this way

**variables-template.css** (contains variables only)

```
$background: green;
```

**variables-modifier.css** (contains variables only)

```
$background: red;
```

**styles-template.css** (contains your styles)

```
body { background-color: $background; }
```

**main.css** (contains your importation logic)

```
@import 'variables-template.css';
@import 'variables-modifier.css';
@import 'styles-template.css';
```

### Bonus: Using the Strawberry framework

Strawberry has been created for this kind of situation!

See [StrawberrySass](https://github.com/strawberrysass/strawberry).